# How can I get similar dependency resolution to Cargo in an existing project with only rustc for code analysis?

Tags: macros, rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

The Rust book mentions that [macros can be expanded](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html#debugging-macro-code) with the command `rustc --pretty expanded`. I'd like to use this for testing some macros I wrote in a crate, by expanding an example file with a command like

```
rustc -Z unstable-options --pretty expanded examples/macro_test.rs
```

`macro_test.rs` would have code that looks like this:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate macro_crate;

use macro_crate::macros::*;

macro_foo! { foo }

fn main() {}
```

However, that results in error 0463, which is that `rustc` doesn't know anything about the crate environment it's in:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `macro_crate`
 --> examples/macro_test.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate macro_test;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

What's the recommended way to work with this? The `cargo` help doesn't have anything directly related as far as I can tell.

Comment: You need to add a dependency for `macro_test`. First see http://doc.crates.io/guide.html for a tutorial how to create a crate and add dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cargo has a `rustc` subcommand for invoking `rustc` with additional arguments.

```
$ cargo rustc --example macro_test -- -Z unstable-options --pretty expanded
```

You can also add `--verbose` before the `--` to get Cargo to print the full `rustc` command line (among other things).